# ¿Donde se especifica la conexión de las tablas de la base de datos en laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel-9

Resulta que tengo un proyecto en laravel 9, he hice un login con un paquete, el cual viene predeterminado, pero quiero cambiarle la entrada a los campos, ya que la base de datos que quiero conectar es otra....
donde se encuentran las definiciones de cada tabla para un campo?

espero me pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si desea modificar el comportamiento de la autenticacion por defecto del starter kit de laravel , la forma mas orgánica es creando tu propia fachada de auth personalizada en laravel , esto te permitirá modificar el nombre de las columnas a las que apunta el login y su comportamiento general.

Te dejo el enlace de la doc https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

Las configuraciones en laravel estan en la carpeta .env ( a veces se llama .envexample)

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=debug
APP_KEY=bxxxxxx
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug
//Aca puedes cambiar las configuraciones de la bdd
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=Ejemplo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

En cuando a las tablas y sus campos esto se puede cambiar en las migraciones de laravel
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, pero mi punto va a cambiarle el nombre a la columna de la base de datos.
Ejemplo: 
tengo un login que el nombre de usuario esta llamado como "Name" pero tengo otra base de datos que se llama "username" entonces ese es el cambio que quiero realizar, y no encuentro donde esta estipulado eso

Comment: No se a que te refieres con una columna de la base de datos?, las bases de datos tienen tablas.. las tablas tienen campos